# Create Unique Field Value by Concatenation

Tags: t-sql

How can you generate a unique value for a field that matches a concatenation of certain fields and a random number

i.e.

First Name: Jim

Last Name: Jones

Field Value: jimjones0345

obviously there's a need to ensure that this value was not populated before.  How would one go about this?

Comment: Is the random value going to be a fixed width? And are you sure there are enough such values for the life of the system and/or what are you going to do when you run out of unique values?

Comment: I'm no longer working on a solution to this question but I know people who would be interested in it's solution.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your using SQL Server 2005 or later...
You might try something like

`update myTable 
set myNewColumn = FirstName+LastName+convert(varchar,(ABS(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS VARBINARY(5)) AS Bigint))));`

Comment: thanks for the approach but the first/last combo with possible duplicates would negate this as a good choice